# How to conclude in conjunctive normal form?

Tags: logic

1.$(p\wedge q)\leftrightarrow r$

2.$((p \wedge q)\rightarrow r)\wedge(r\rightarrow(p\wedge q))$

3.$(\neg( p \wedge q)\vee r)\wedge (\neg r \vee((p\wedge q))$

4.$(\neg p \vee \neg q\vee r)\wedge ((\neg r \vee p) \wedge (\neg r \vee q))$

Do I conclude with this:

$\{\neg p; \neg q ; r\}\{\neg r; p\}\{\neg r; q\}$?

Comment: What does $;$ mean?

Comment: In the third line, you have written $\wedge$ instead of $\vee$ in the subformula $(\neg p \vee \neg q) \wedge r$.

Comment: @mrp it's standard notations to say that things are separated, used first by Arabic mathematicians in the middle ages, and a rule in some countries like Francophone countries.
"punctuation is not a matter of style, but rather a matter of rules." lik said Rob Haron on M.O

Comment: @DeeDuu, your right, I have corrected it, I still have to figure out what is the result from this editing.

Comment: You do have a conjunctive normal form now, and all the steps seem correct; so if your task is to give CNF, you're finished. Or do you have to do something else?

Comment: @No, it's okay, thanks, I wasn't sure about how to conclude whith CNF, if there were academic standards to write the proof... Thanks!